# Any possible to make two instantiations be equal in java?

Tags: java

I need to achieve this result:

```
public class question{
  public static void main(String[]arg){
    A a1=new A();
    A a2=new A(2);
    assert a2.equals(a1);
    }
  }
```

So I have tried:

```
class A{
    A(){
    return; 
    }
    A(int x){
    return;
    }
}

public class d22 {
      public static void main(String[]arg){
            A a1=new A();
            A a2=new A(2);
            assert a2.equals(a1);
            }
}
```

But obviously it's not working, is there any way to achieve the code upper? Thx.

Comment: Why should they be equal? There needs to be rules that you can implement in the `equals(...)` method of your class.

Comment: can you even use the assert keyword with equals() in Java? Is that considered an expression? can you replace equals() with the == operator?

Comment: You can `assert` any boolean condition in Java. Check the language spec and tutorials for such questions.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing particularly magical about `equals` - it's a plain jane method defined in java.lang.Object.

You can override it.

This weird idea would work:

```
class A {
    @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return other instanceof A;
    }
}
```

would mean any A is equal to any other.

Comment: You should also Override `hashCode()`: `return 1`

Answer (score 0):

actually,the java object which is created by the key word new is allocated in the heap.So the result is false if you want compare a1 with a2,because the default equals method is to compare the object memory address.If you want compare two object ,you should rewrite the equals method to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

All classes in Java extends default Object class which contains method's `equals()` and `toString()`. `Equals()` method is used to compare instance of that particular class against another variable. You can override this method to define how equals should behave.

```
class A {
    @Override 
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!other instance of A) return false; // other is not same type as this class
        if (other == this) return true; // both variables point to same object
        return true; // you can compare other class attributes here
    }
}
```

By default equals will return true if you are comparing two variables that point to same object. That means in your case that you obtain false when calling `equals` since your two variables point to different object created by `new` operator and you have not overriden `equals()` method to get different behavior than default one.